# Taking a snapshot on elasticsearch in one system and restoring that snapshot on another system

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have setup Elasticsearch on one system and I have been regularly taking backup by creating a repository and registering it and also created a snapshot.

I have taken the backup of all the Indices into a single snapshot and now I want to restore them to a cluster on a different system.

How to do this operation.

I tried traditional copy and paste method. I copied the backup repository which contained the snapshot and pasted them on a different repository on a different system.

And on that system I ran _restore operation with the same snapshot name. But it did not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to [register a repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-filesystem-repository.html) on your target cluster with the file system location where you copied your snapshots taken on the source cluster.

```
PUT _snapshot/my_fs_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/path/to/your/snapshots"
  }
}
```

Then, once the repository is registered on your new cluster, you can [restore your snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html)

```
POST _snapshot/my_fs_backup/my_snapshot_2099.05.06/_restore
{
  "indices": "my-index-1,my-index-2"
}
```